# Why does this return [], not ["stuff"]?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
f = open("new.txt", "w+")
f.write("stuff")
content = f.read().splitlines()
print(content)
```

When I run it, it shows: `[]`

Why don't I get `["stuff"]`?

Comment: Because the cursor is at the end of the file when you read.

Comment: how do I move the cursor to the beginning?

Comment: You can use seek.

Comment: You should use a context manager to handle file objects.

Comment: As an aside, don't do `f.read().splitlines()`, just use `list(f)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you opened the file for writing,  so the current file position points to the end of the file after your wrote stuff.

Proper code would be something like that

```
fw = open("new.txt", "w+")
fw.write("stuff")
fw.close()

fr = open("new.txt", "r")
content = f.read().splitlines()
print(content)
```

Comment: it's opened in write/read mode, so you could just move the cursor to the beginning and read it, but generally, I think the above is a better approach. Rarely do you need to be doing a lot of file seeking in Python.